# creating an option list with an optiongroup dynamicly using php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a list of members in an HTML option list, but i want it to be divided according to the department of each member, because every member is working in aone department of the company .
Here is the code i tried to use but was unsuccessful :

```
    <?php
   echo'<select size=1 name="Name List">'."\n";
   echo'<option value="-1">--Name List--</option>'."\n";
   $result1=mysql_query("select department from users");

   while($data1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

   echo'<optgroup value="'.$data1[0].'">'.$data1['department'];

    $result=mysql_query('select username from users where department="'.$data1['department'].'" ');

   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   echo'<option value="'.$data[0].'">'.$data['username'];
   echo'</option>'."\n";
   }
   echo'</optgroup>'."\n";
   }
   echo'</select>'."\n";
   mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Comment: you mean you want to have more than one HTML option dynamically for each departments?

Comment: For each department i want to list the names of every one working in it

Comment: do you have one table to store members and department or you have one table for members and another for departments?

Answer (score 0):

first of all its more better to have separate tables one for members and another for departments.

every tables have their own id and other fields.in this case you need to bring department_id in members table as foreign key.

departments table:

[image]

members table:

[image]

so next in your code you should join these two tables to get related data's:

code:

```
  <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
  mysql_select_db("test");

  $sql = "select members.name as mem_name,departments.name as dep_name 
  from members 
  left join department 
  on 
  members.department_id = departments.id 
  order by members.name asc";

  $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

  while ($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
     echo '<optgroup label="'.$row['dep_name'].'">\n';
     echo '<option value="'.$row['mem_name'].'">'.$row['mem_name'].'</option>\n';
     echo '</optgroup>\n';  
  }
  ?>
```

Result:

[image]